# Why? Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js

I keep getting this error: ***Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.***

I have read other posts but I don't understand. I dont have any double callbacks or anything. Where in my code is causing this error?

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/root/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:666:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/root/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:146:12)
    at fn (/root/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:900:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/root/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:330:12)
    at View.render (/root/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/root/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:530:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/root/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:904:7)
    at Query. (/root/tutsplus/server4.js:25:7)
    at Query.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

```
var express = require('express'), app = express();
var mysql   = require('mysql');

app.get('/', function(req,res) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'xxxx',
        database: 'store'
    });

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * from category');

    query.on('result', function(row) {

        var category = row.category_name;

        res.render('xxxx.jade', {
            category: category
        });
    });

}); // app.get

app.listen(80, function() {

    console.log('we are logged in');
});
```

Comment: This particular error is nearly always because of improper handling of asynchronous operations that cause things to be out of sequence in the sending the response.

Comment: Is there anything in my code that is causing this problem? Where should I be looking?

Comment: Please post the stack-trace of the error ( `error.stack` ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, this issue is nearly always caused by improper handling of asynchronous operations which causes pieces of the response to be called out of order.

Per the code example [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) that uses `.on()`, you need to end the request only when you get:

```
query.on('end', function() {
     // all rows have been received
});
```

I think you are probably calling `res.render()` more than once because you're calling it in `query.on('result', ...)` rather than in `query.on('end', ....)` after all the data has been collected.

The fact that you're doing it in:

```
query.on('result', ...)
```

is probably the wrong timing issue causing the problem.

---

From the mysql nodejs connector documentation, here's an example:

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts');
query
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
  })
  .on('fields', function(fields) {
    // the field packets for the rows to follow
  })
  .on('result', function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    connection.pause();

    processRow(row, function() {
      connection.resume();
    });
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // all rows have been received
  });
```

Comment: The OP has modified his Q to remove the call to `res.end()`.

Comment: @Dai - it is hard to keep up with a changing question.  One additional issue is that they shouldn't be calling `res.render()` until all data has been received.  The main point is that one should gather all the data and then when all data has been received, they can create the response with `res.render()`.

Comment: @Dai `result` is emitted for each row. If there is more than one row, `res.render()` will be called multiple times.