# NodeJS SQL Login Error (ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, npm

Hello I'm pretty new to nodeJS and I'm having an issue which I believe the catalyst is in the second if statement nested in "db.query..." in the code below. Im getting an error that says `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` but I'm not quite sure how to fix this situation? I'm trying to create a login form which gets the information from mysql.

```
  app.post('/login',(req, res) =>{

        const { email, password } = req.body //pulls name="email" from html

        if(email && password){

            db.query('SELECT * from users WHERE email = ? ;',[email], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result) {
                    if(result[0].password === password){
                        req.session.userId = result[0].uid
                        return res.redirect('/home')
                    }
                }     
                console.log(result[0].email)
              });

        }
        res.redirect('/login')
    });
```

Comment: did you have  a look here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895329/why-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait until your query execution completes.
In Your code the response was send to client before your query returns result.

You can try something like following.

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) =>{

    const { email, password } = req.body //pulls name="email" from html

    if(email && password){
        try {
          let result = await db.query('SELECT * from users WHERE email = ? ;',[email]);
          if (result) {
            if(result[0].password === password){
              req.session.userId = result[0].uid
              return res.redirect('/home')
            } else {
              res.redirect('/login')
            }
          }
       } catch(e) => {
         res.redirect('/login')
       }
   }
}
```